Drools regexp on collection
I want to select nested objects that have a list of string that at least one matches regular a expression.
Here what I want to achieve, that doesn't work because "contains" uses strict equality.
rule "Get instances if at least one SeriesDescription matches *Perfusion* "

when    
    $session: /session
    $instances: /session/instances [ getTagValues(Tag.SeriesDescription) contains "*Perfusion*" ]

then    
    System.out.println("At least one Instance has one Series Description containing value like '*Perfusion*'");
end

I wan to do that with the "matches" operator, but for that I have to itterate over the list of string that return the getTagValues(Tag.SeriesDescription) method.
